# Merging data sets based on timestamp but there has to be 48hrs between the timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, time-series

**UPDATE:**

**This is how I currently matched my data frames, on matching date stamps and patient number. I want to match on patient number and datestamp 48h earlier. I took hours and seconds away to gather more matching entries**

[How I changed time stamps to date stamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXCC5.png)

[How I merged the labels to the set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaFyP.png)

**Dummy samples of [feature set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlnaz.png)  (logs) and [label set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Vm6.png) (scores)**

**Dummy [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4B3o.png)**

**----------------------------------------------------------**

I created a data frame from 2 sources:

1. Logs that nurses wrote over 2020, including timestamp and patient number
2. Patient vitality scores over 2020, including timestamp and patient number

I want to predict the vitality scores off of the nurses' logs, using NLP and binary classification.

I think I need to create a new data set, where I have the logs, scores and patient numbers. The important thing is:

**I need logs that were written 48hrs prior to scoring for each patient. So difference between **log_time** and **score_time** should be 2 roughly days.**

What should the timestamps look like? Should I make them numerical?

The time stamps are written like this: **09MAR2020:23:06:00**
I created date stamps like this: **09MAR20**
Maybe I should convert it to something like this: **03-09-20-00:00:00?**

If anyone could give me any tips, that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please add sample input data and expected output. in case you have tried some code , please add that as well

Comment: I created some dummy data, I cannot share the real data

Comment: I find it strange that you do not merge the cells by patient number. What do you do if there have been several patients during the same hour? Is the `datestamp scoring` exactly 48 hours ahead or behind the `datestamp log`? Thats inconsistent in your expected output.

Can you share some real Python-code to create the pandas-dataframes?

Comment: I tried to merge on patient number and datestamp at the same time. And no, it's not exactly 48h but by removing seconds and hours I thought I could round off to roughly 48h. I know there's a typo in my expected output. I will upload some code and change the output picture.

Comment: A copy-pastable python code would be really nice, so we can play easily with it. Nevermind, my suggestion would be, that you perform an outer join on the patient number and then drop lines where the time-difference is not what you want. I assume you use pandas? You can perform operations using the Timestamp and the Timedelta there.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using pandas indeed. I'm now using timestamp to convert to datetime objects, I think I want to create a new column that's the timestamps minus 48h and then merge the label set to that.

Comment: And I can't copy paste anything from my VM to my computer, the environment is protected so I could only take screenshots.